# Pandas: Merging two Dataframe, add columns and delete duplicate rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation, row

I have two dataframes, let's say, material inventory reports, for Jan and Feb:

January Report

```
code  description    qty_jan   amount_jan

WP1   Wooden Part-1  1000      50000
MP1   Metal Part-1   500       5000
GL1   Glass-1        100       2500
```

February Report

```
code  description    qty_feb   amount_feb

WP1   Wooden Part-1  1200      60000
MP2   Metal Part-2   300       3000
GL1   Glass-1        50        1250
GL2   Glass-2        200       5000
```

To monitor the progress of each material inventory, I would like to merge two reports, as follows:

```
code  description    qty_jan   amount_jan    qty_feb   amount_feb

WP1   Wooden Part-1  1000      50000         1200      60000
MP1   Metal Part-1   500       5000          0         0   
MP2   Metal Part-2   0         0             300       3000
GL1   Glass-1        100       2500          50        1250
GL2   Glass-2        0         0             200       5000
```

Note: Materials that are not listed in a report, are considered zero stock.

How to merge these two reports?

Comment: So in sample data are no duplicated rows? Is possible create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) also with duplicated rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use outer join in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and then replace missing values to `0`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['code','description'], how='outer').fillna(0)
print (df)
v  code    description  qty_jan  amount_jan  qty_feb  amount_feb
0  WP1  Wooden Part-1   1000.0     50000.0   1200.0     60000.0
1  MP1   Metal Part-1    500.0      5000.0      0.0         0.0
2  GL1        Glass-1    100.0      2500.0     50.0      1250.0
3  MP2   Metal Part-2      0.0         0.0    300.0      3000.0
4  GL2        Glass-2      0.0         0.0    200.0      5000.0
```

Another idea with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1.set_index(['code','description']), 
                df2.set_index(['code','description'])], axis=1).fillna(0).reset_index()
print (df)
  code    description  qty_jan  amount_jan  qty_feb  amount_feb
0  GL1        Glass-1    100.0      2500.0     50.0      1250.0
1  GL2        Glass-2      0.0         0.0    200.0      5000.0
2  MP1   Metal Part-1    500.0      5000.0      0.0         0.0
3  MP2   Metal Part-2      0.0         0.0    300.0      3000.0
4  WP1  Wooden Part-1   1000.0     50000.0   1200.0     60000.0
```

Comment: Very fast answer. Thanks very much.